# Boolean indexing between two different Dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have two different Dataframes of different lengths with one common column: `date`, and I want to boolean index it such that it matches the dates from `df2` onto `df1` on the rows where they are the same. The first Dataframe, `df1` has daily dates, whereas `df2` has gaps between the dates.

DF1:

```
             date   usd_am   usd_pm   usd_avg
13235  2020-05-14  1716.40  1731.60  1724.000
13236  2020-05-15  1734.85  1735.35  1735.100
13237  2020-05-18  1756.90  1734.70  1745.800
13238  2020-05-19  1735.25  1737.95  1736.600
13239  2020-05-20  1750.05  1748.30  1749.175

(13240, 4)
```

DF2:

```
            day        date          time
1863   Thursday  2050-09-01   10:30:54 am
1864     Friday  2050-09-30   06:31:48 pm
1865     Sunday  2050-10-30   04:16:00 am
1866     Monday  2050-11-28   04:09:48 pm
1867  Wednesday  2050-12-28   06:15:36 am

(1868, 3)
```

Both date columns have been made uniform in format and are stored as strings.

I tried this: 
`df1['match'] = df1[df1['date'] == df2['date']]`

but I got this error:
`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

The expected output should be:

DF1:

```
             date   usd_am   usd_pm   usd_avg  match
13235  2020-05-14  1716.40  1731.60  1724.000  False
13236  2020-05-15  1734.85  1735.35  1735.100  True
13237  2020-05-18  1756.90  1734.70  1745.800  True
13238  2020-05-19  1735.25  1737.95  1736.600  True
13239  2020-05-20  1750.05  1748.30  1749.175  False
```

where if the match value is True, then the date exists in `df2` as well.

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Comment: Sure, it's been updated. @FrancisWebb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pandas isin to generate new column and then adding it on with the desired name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

```
    df2['match'] = df2['date'].isin(df1['date'])
```